# How to activate a class ONLY after receiving user input variable?

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, user-input, actionlistener

I want to activate a certain class after getting user input. However it is implemented concurrently with the swing frame for user input. So it does not effectively receive user input variable and gives "null pointer" exception.

I searched for Internet and get ideas of using "ActionListener" Interface, but without substance to trigger an action(for addActionListener), it is not working as intended.

Here comes main entry of the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        new Controller();
    }
```

and Controller

```
private ActionListener listener;

public Controller(){
    SwingUtilities.invoke(new MyRunnable(listener));
}
```

and MyRunnable

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable, ActionListener{

    private ActionListener listener;
    private List<Player> playerInfo;
    private List<Node> playerNode;

    public MyRunnable(ActionListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        new NCT(playerInfo, playerNode);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Player> setAllPlayers() {
        return playerInfo = listener.setAllPlayers();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Node> setAllNodes() {
        return playerNode = listener.setAllNodes();
    }
```

In implementing ActionListener requires @Override of 2 methods because the original source of action class suppose to bring userinput.

```
public PlayerRoles(ActionListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
-----Here are setAllPlayers and setAllNodes----
```

What am I missing here?
I know I need to put "addActionListener" to somewhere but I have no idea where to put..
please help me..

Thank you~!!!

Comment: ActionListeners are attached to Swing UI components.. if you want a listener to run your class, the listener would wait for the user to interact with whatever component it's attached to. You'd do well to provide code for your UI rather than the class that you're trying to run -- that's not where the solution is.

Comment: ``Listener`` are a specific part of the Swing UI system. A listener's job is usually to take an input from a user (perhaps a button click) and then quickly handle this.